# β is converted to Ã¢ in

Tags: conversion

i am using rtf2latex in windows 8.1 when i am trying to converting i got the 
following results:

original content

```
AUWDBE
a) 95β992   
b) 25β693       
c) 3596β2       
d) 35β629       
e) 35β692
```

converted content

```
%&pdfLaTeX
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{STIXGeneral}
\else
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\newcommand{\tab}{\hspace{5mm}}

\begin{document}

\baselineskip=18pt
\leftskip=-9pt
AUWDBE

a) 95Ã¢992\tab 

b) 25Ã¢693\tab \tab 

c) 3596Ã¢2\tab \tab 

d) 35Ã¢629\tab \tab 

e) 35Ã¢692

\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your question? Maybe, how to get `rtf2latex` to handle the character `β` correctly?

Comment: sorry for my english.
         how to handle that character.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are saving TeX as utf8 and opening it as latin1 or similar...

Comment: sorry, i am just using the converting tool "rtf2latex2e.exe" to convert the "RTF" file and i using wordpad to open the converted file

Comment: rtf2latex2e creates utf8 files. Have you tried to open the TeX file in another editor (like emacs)?

Comment: @Roberto I apologize for the assumption, but I believe that will end poorly (speaking as an emacs enthusiast)... Madhan, try opening the file with notepad.  Does it display legibly?

Comment: @MadhanSeeman If it does display legibly, try re-saving as UTF8.  Click Save-As and under the file name, there should be a drop down for the file encoding.  Choose something that sounds like "Unicode" or "UTF8", then try again.

Comment: Thanks,
now it is displaying like this :   a) 95â992\tab 

    b) 25â693\tab \tab 

    c) 3596â2\tab \tab 

    d) 35â629\tab \tab 

    e) 35â692